# Chromium: gnome keyring unlocked without password?

Tags: google-chrome, gnome, arch-linux, chromium, gnome-keyring

When starting `chromium` (with default keyring locked) it asks for the password to unlock the keyring (so that I can skim through my saved passwords afterwards). This gnome keyring window offers two options - either `Cancel` or `Unlock`. When I enter the password and press `Unlock` everything works as expected (I can see my saved passwords), but when I press `Cancel` and navigate to Settings try to see my saved passwords... it works again! **I can see the passwords without unlocking the keyring.**

When I manually launch `seahorse` and manually *lock* the keyring, the passwords in `chromium` disappear. If I then restart `chromium` and press `Cancel` in password asking window **I can see my passwords again**.

```
Arch Linux

chromium 52.0.2743.85

gnome-keyring 3.20.0

$ seahorse -v
seahorse 3.20.0
GNUPG: /usr/bin/gpg2 (2.1.12)

$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.14
libgcrypt 1.7.2
```

Is it a bug? Should I report it?

**UPD**
I tried `chromium --password-store=gnome` and I get:

```
** Message: Remote error from secret service: org.freedesktop.Secret.Error.IsLocked: Cannot get secret of a locked object
[20736:20757:0811/132248:ERROR:native_backend_libsecret.cc(517)] Unable to load secret itemCannot get secret of a locked object
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
** Message: Remote error from secret service: org.freedesktop.Secret.Error.IsLocked: Cannot create an item in a locked collection
[20736:20757:0811/132251:ERROR:native_backend_libsecret.cc(384)] Libsecret add raw login failed: Cannot create an item in a locked collection
[201:201:0811/132304:ERROR:PlatformKeyboardEvent.cpp(84)] Not implemented reached in static bool blink::PlatformKeyboardEvent::currentCapsLockState()
```

Although it starts normally etc. After pressing `Cancel` the passwords are still visible.

**UPD2**

Some discussion around `unable to load secret item` can be found [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=508458).

Comment: Do you have sync enabled in Chrome?

Comment: Yes, I do have.

Answer (score 2):

Alongside GNOME Keyring and KWallet, Chrome also has a built-in (SQLite-based) unencrypted database, and uses it if both Keyring and KWallet are unusable. (This apparently includes the keyring being merely locked...)

Since you have sync enabled, Chrome merely downloads all passwords from the syncserver again, this time storing them in the internal database.

Using `--password-store=gnome` might avoid this. (OTOH, the internal store is much faster.)

Comment: There's no place here, I'll update my question.